# EF Creating Extra Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Using EF6, I have created a simple POCO named Account to track data about the user:

```
public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //Others
}
```

This Account object is apart of the following DbContext (stripped for brevity):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //constructor
    //other DBSets

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts {get;set;}
}
```

The OnModelCreating removes the PluralTableNamesConvention, so it successfully creates a table named "Account" with the correct properties.

I also have the ApplicationDbContext, which contains the following definition for ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //GenerateUserIdentityAsync method....

    public virtual Account AccountInfo { get; set; }
}
```

The intent is to be able to create a user, then make calls such as

```
myStuff.SearchByName(user.AccountInfo.FirstName)
```

**PROBLEM:**
When I create a user and EF generates the ASP.net identity tables, it ALSO creates a table named "Accounts".  All users created have their information sent into the "Accounts" table, not the original "Account" table that I intended to use.

I am not sure how force the IdentityDbContext to use only the original Account table and not generate its own.  I have tried:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("Account");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

but it returns the following.  Any help would be appreciated :)

*Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.*

Comment: Have you enabled migrations in the project? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: @Praval'Shaun'Tirubeni yes, migrations are enabled in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so not sure if this is going to be a valid answer or not. But I created a MVC4/EF5 project a while ago and had to do something similar. I used the WebSecurity Identity Framework or whatever it's called (Think there is a different identity framework now). Essentially all I had to do was put a few lines of code in the Application_Start method of the Global.ascx.

```
// Tells membership provider to use the Baller table too store user profile information
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("BallSoHardContext", "Baller", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
}
```

So I just tell it to use the "Baller table" to store the information. You might be using a different identity framework since you are using EF6, but you should be able to find something similar in the API.

[My Github project if you want to look through the code.](https://github.com/patkremer/BallHard/blob/master/BallSoHard/Global.asax.cs)